# New column based on logic on two other column values to find outlier

Tags: python, pandas, logic

Is there a way to apply logic to data frame based on other column value:

```
I have DF:
Price    Upper_limit      Lower_Limit
10         9.5                 9
5           7                  6
```

Also is there a way to add a column `outlier` so the comparison has to be done for each row ?

```
if Price    < Lower_limit      or      Price    > Upper_limit      :    1
else: 0
```

Expected output:

```
Price    Upper_limit      Lower_Limit    Outlier
10         9.5                 9            1
5           7                  6            0
```

I have  tried with a loop and `iloc[]` but doesn't seems to work.

Comment: `if price < Upper_limit or Price > Upper_limit : 1 else: 0` you probably mean to have "Lower_limit" somewhere in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following. Changed my solution as per @rafaelc

```
df['outlier']=(df['Price'].gt(df['Upper_limit']) | df['Price'].lt(df['Lower_Limit'])).astype(int)
```

Output will be as follows.

```
    price   Upper_limit Lower_Limit outlier
0   10      9.5         9               1
1   5       6.0         7               0
```

Comment: DOWN VOTER, please do mention reason for down vote, so that can improve myself in learning Pandas?

Comment: Any reasons to do `astype(int)` ?

Comment: @rafaelc, To make integer and float comparison is the only reason I have put it in that way. Apologies I am new to Pandas and learning, if any improvements there kindly do lemme know will edit it, thank you.

Comment: No problem, I just felt I needed to signlize to OP that this solution can be flaky. For example, when you convert to integer, you will lose precision. `9.5` will become `9.0` and a value of `9.3` could be mistakenly classified as an outlier

Comment: @rafaelc, thank you for pointing that corner case. If you could suggest any improvements on top of your head now, I cold fix it, mean while I too googling for same, cheers.

Comment: I think the solution would be something as simple as `(df['Price'].gt(df['Upper_limit']) | df['Price'].lt(df['Lower_Limit'])).astype(int)` . The problem is that OP has a `Lower_limit` greater than `Upper_limit` in the second row, which doesn't make any sense haha

Comment: @rafaelc, Thank you for letting know, I have edited my answer, appreciate your guidance here, cheers.

Comment: We'll just need OP's input on how come `7` is the lower limit and `6` is the upper limit in that second row ;p

Comment: Thank you everyone, I have fixed some typing errors and I really appreciate you all.
English not my first language by the way

Comment: @rafaelc thank you for improving RavinderSingh13 idea, Fixed the typing mistake!
my bad :D

Answer (score 0):

```
outlier = []

static = []

for i in range(len(DF['obs_date'])):

    if DF['Upper_band'].iloc[i] < DF['price'].iloc[i] or DF['price'].iloc[i] < DF['Lower_band'].iloc[i]:

        outlier.append('1')

    else:

        outlier.append('0')    

    if DF['return'].iloc[i] == 0:

        static.append('1')

    else:

        static.append('0')


DF['outlier'] = outlier

DF['static'] = static
```

This is my current [ugly!] solution, it include logic testing on an addition outlier statistic.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should works:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   df['Outlier'] = ~(row['Upper_limit'] <= row['Price'] <= row['Lower_limit']) * 1

print(df)
```